# Access variable outside function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a nodejs + express + mongodb project. I'm using monk for accessing my mongo DB.

```
var myvar;
var myCollection = db.get('myCollection');
myCollection.find({},function(e,docs){
myvar = docs;
})
console.log(myvar)
```

This outputs undefined. If I try to output the object inside the function, there is no problem.
How can I save the object globally?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180896/how-to-return-mongoose-results-from-the-find-method).  It covers mongoose, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I achieved what I wanted using async. Thanks!