# Iterate mongoose object with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i put `<%= products %>` into my view, it prints [Object Object] so I'm assuming that the mongoose resultset is an object. Now, I am trying to loop over `products` object but it says `products.forEach is not a function`.

This is my `index route`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../model/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var products = Product.find();
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', products: products });
});

module.exports = router;
```

with the code above,I am just retrieving it from the db and passing it as an object. I have tried using `var products = Product.find({}).toArray();` but got no luck. And another solution I tried is using this code:

```js
  var products = Product.find();
  var data = JSON.stringify(products);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', products: data });
```

but I am getting the infamous `Converting circular structure to JSON`error.

This is my `index view`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

  <% products.forEach(function(product) { %>
   <p><%= product.title %></p>
  <% }); %>
  </body>
</html>
```

lastly this is my `Product Schema`:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
 imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
 title: { type: String, required: true },
 description: { type: String, required: true },
 price: { type: Number, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

How is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: `find()` is async.. You need a promise to get the results ..
related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180896/how-to-return-mongoose-results-from-the-find-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is `async` you need to get result from promise do it like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find({}, function(err, products) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', products: products });
  });
});
```